# How to generate unique random numbers in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, unique

I need to generate m unique random numbers in range 1 to n. Currently what I have implemented is:

```
round(rand(1,m)*(n-1)+1)
```

However, some numbers are repeated in the array. How can I get only unique numbers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html).

From the description:

> `p = randperm(n,k)` returns a row vector containing k unique integers
>   selected randomly from 1 to n inclusive.

Thus, `randperm(6,3)`
might be the vector

```
[4 2 5]
```

## Update

The two argument version of randperm only appeared in R2011b, so if you are using an earlier version of MATLAB then you will see that error. In this case, use:

```
A = randperm(n); 
A = A(1:m);
```

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out above, in Matlab versions older than R2011b `randperm` only accepts one input argument. In that case the easiest approach, assuming you have the Statistics Toolbx, is to use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
randsample(n,m)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `randperm` approach described by [@Stewie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21830630/2338750) appears to be the way to go in most cases. However if you can only use Matlab with 1 input argument and `n` is really large, it may not be feasible to use `randperm` on all numbers and select the first few. In this case here is what you can do:

1. Generate an integer between 1 and `n`
2. Generate an integer between 1 and `n-1`, this is the choice out of the available integers.
3. Repeat until you have `m` numbers

This can be done with `randi` and could even be vectorized by just drawing a lot of random numbers at each step until the unique amount is correct.

Comment: This works but is less time efficient. The reason is that he has to write code to find the value of the indexed integer.

Comment: @George Less efficient is relative. I didn't see any solution yet for pre-2011b that can deal with `n = 1e11` or so hence I think this still adds something.

Comment: It certainly does, but I think it would be more efficient to just implement the latest version of randperm.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Shuffle](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27076-shuffle), from the MATLAB File Exchange.

```
Index = Shuffle(n, 'index', m);
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by sorting a random vector of floats:

```
[i,i]=sort(rand(1,range));
output=i(1:m);
```