# Assign ones to random locations in 3D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 20x20x4 matrix of zeros, named `A`. I want to place ones in random location, but with the restrictions below.

The sum of ones in `A(:,:,1)` and `A(:,:,2)` and `A(:,:,3)` and `A(:,:,4)` must be 50 , 60, 120 and 90 respectively and also these elements (I mean cells that have 1 as a value) shouldn't be overlay to each other.

How can this be done in MATLAB? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A way to ensure that no elements overlay each other is by creating 320 unique values between 1 and 400, and add 0, 50, 60, 120 to the corresponding elements in a loop.

```
b = [50, 60, 120, 90];
ind = randperm(n*n, sum(b));

A = zeros(n,n,4);
bb = [0 cumsum(b)]; 
for k = 1:size(A,3)     
   A((k-1)*n*n + ind(bb(k)+1:bb(k+1))) = 1;
end
```

<sub>Edited according to comment by knedlsepp</sub>

Comment: Very clever approach!

Comment: Thank you for your help. but there is a problem. when I entered the second line `ind = randperm(n*n, sum(b));`, I got the error: `Error using ==> randperm` , `Too many input arguments`. Thanks

Comment: You are probably using a Matlab version older than R2011b. If so, do something like: `all_ind = randperm(n*n)`, and `ind = all_ind(1:sum(b))`. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830572/how-to-generate-unique-random-numbers-in-matlab/21830630#21830630).